# Checking compactness of $[0,1]$ using the definition

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

By definition a set is compact if every open covering has a finite subcover.
I made an open covering of $[0,1]$ by taking a fixed $\epsilon= \dfrac1{10,00000}$ (or even more small) radius neighborhood around each point in $[0,1$]. But I could not find its finite subcover. By Heine-Borel theorem it's clear that it will be compact. But, I was trying to use definition but could not find its finite subcover.

Comment: You might need a million or so of these intervals...

Comment: Take the interval around zero, then the one around 0.0000005...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of $\varepsilon$ doesn't matter. Take the intervals $(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$, $(-\varepsilon/2,3\varepsilon/2)$, $(0,2\varepsilon)$, and so on…

Comment: But to get a finite subcover  i feel size of epsilon matters here.

Comment: No, it does not. As $\varepsilon$ gets smaller, you will need more and more intervals. Nevertheless, there will always be a finite set of such intervals that will cover $[0,1]$.

Comment: Ok,got it.Thank you

Comment: @SimonTerrington No. I wrote what I meant.

Comment: OK @JoséCarlosSantos I get that and it was my mistake. I was confused by the fact that  the intervals in your cover overlap so much. Could it just have gone $(-\epsilon, \epsilon),(0,2\ \epsilon),(\epsilon, 3 \epsilon)$? Can't we just live without the second term?

Comment: Sure. Indeed, there is no need that the intervals overlap so much as in my answer. And $(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$, $(\varepsilon/2,5\varepsilon/2)$, $(2\varepsilon,4\varepsilon)$ and so on would also work.

Answer (score 1):

Hi OK this is a good fundamental question about compactness.

If you take neighbourhoods of width $1/1,000,000$ around $0$,$1/1,000,000$,$2/1,000,000$,$3/1,000,000$,$4/1,000,000$,$\dots$, $999,999/1,000,000$ and $1$ then this covers the space and is finite (even though it is very big). As epsilon gets smaller then the number of sets that is required increases (in inverse proportion to epsilon) but it will always be finite.

Comment: Thank you for the tick Kajal but what is with the vote-downs guys? Is there something I should know? :) It's mathematically correct? Isn't it?